# apache 2.4 - what triggers an ErrorDocument 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4, errordocument

I know that a 404 error means Page Not Found error. But why is apache triggering `ErrorDocument 404` when pointing to a php script? What is that **exactly** that makes apache 2.4 fire this directive with error code 404??

Answer (score 0):

I found the error! 
The path to my script was: domain.com/dir/dir2/script.php. I just found that "dir2" was actually a file and not a directory! After removing that file, the script was reached and executed correctly. No more `ErrorDocument 404`. I hope this helps others.